# phpmyadmin displaying white page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have wamp server installed on a windows amazon ec2 instance.

Phpmyadmin opens up fine, displaying the home page. But when i click on anything, e.g. databases, import, export etc. it just displays the list of databases on the left side and a blank white page in the middle. Heres a screenshot

http://tinypic.com/r/2yv7z3o/6

I have error logging turned on but no errors appear in the error log.

I can't find a solution to this problem so any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any browser errors if you turn on Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try completely uninstalling the program you're using, then redownload XAMPP for windows. I downloaded from here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641. Here is a tutorial for Windows 8: http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/12/how-to-install-xampp-1-8-on-windows-8/. You should be good after that.